# UWP change mobile hotspot edit to disable

Tags: uwp, windows-10, hotspot

I write an UWP app to control mobile-hotspot.
In this app, it can modify mobile-hotspot ssid and password to special word, 
but it also can modify by Network&Internet in control panel.

So, I want disable mobile-hotspot edit option in control panel when this app is running.

Is this could be possible?

[image: Disable this option]

Answer (score 0):

The app's behavior cannot affect system setting. It does not follow UWP design purpose(security reason). So I don't think it is possible for you. Please consider let your customer know that your app can already meet their need and they don't need to set it themselves from system settings.